# Optimise file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a small php script which allows me to upload image file on the server. The only problem is that it takes a whole life to upload a 586 kilobytes image file. It there anyway to optimise this?. I'm running a 256kb/s download and 58 kb/s upload. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly then you cannot optimise the process in its current form. What you can conisder though is switching to a more elegant file upload solution such as [SWFupload](http://www.swfupload.org/), [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) *(to name a few)*. This will provide you with a graphical file upload progress bar so you dont have the same sense of the browser hanging.

Comment: As i understand his problem is the speed (or lack of speed) not the solution itself. :(

Comment: yes, thats my understanding too. My solution just means the lack of speed is handled in a more elegant manner with visual cues about the progress which imv is an improvement.

Comment: I just tried the SWFuploader and it seams to uplaod faster. thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your upload bandwidth. I don't think you can optimize this. You can optimize your image but not your upload speed.